# Large form validation structure

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm currently building a form manager in PHP to validate large forms.

I'm wondering what is the best structure for that, because the number of fields will be different each time.

I'm already filtering the field to validate by using a prefix (ex : 'user_name', will be validated, but 'name' no).

My real problem is for the validation : I must check the type of the field (mail, zipcode, phone...)
AND check that the value for this type of field is valid.

I thought that I could use HTML5 Custom data" (ex: data-fieldtype="zipcode"), but i didn't know that the server can't get this attribute...

What's the way to go ?

I could use 2 inputs per field, one for the value and one for the type, but it looks really stupid !

Thanks if you can help.

EDIT :

Your answers are all interesting, i don't know which is best.
I will probably make a mix between your solutions, depending of the kind of form.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you use any framework ? (Drupal, CI, Symfony, etc ?)

Comment: Nope, from scratch...

Comment: If you need validation rules in html, maybe you can make input name as: var_name|var_type|validation_rules (if forms are generated on server side), and then process it in php... 'I' - as separator between name, type, and rules...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methinks, this shouldn't be played via the Browser without further thought: A malicious user would be able to manipulate a "INT ONLY" field into being freetext, and your application would suddenly have to deal with freetext in a field, that is thought to be validated as an integer (und thus e.g. safe for SQL).

You have two approaches:

- Have your form validation structure stored in the DB, and submit a single hidden field, that carries the ID of the validation structure. On receiving the request, your script would request the structure from the DB, unserialize it, and work on it.
- If you really need to go through the browser, serialize your validation structure, base64-encode it and use it as a single hidden field. For the reasons stated above, it is mandatory to authenticate this value, either hashing (concatenate with another string only known to the server, hash it, send the hash as a second hidden field, on next request verify the hash is correct) or by encryption (encrypt the serialized data before the browser roundtrip, decrypt afterwards, key known only to the server)

Both would make your prefix-trick unnecessary, increasing readability and maintainability.

Comment: You are right, i forgot the security problem.
The serialization of the structure seems to be the best solution to me.
But there is another problem : it's useful for server-generated forms, but I also have some little forms that will be written manually. Should I make 2 different validation classes ? One for big random forms, and one for little forms thats will never change?

Comment: I Recommend you create a little helper script in JS, that parsesthe manual-designed forms and sends the result to the server as a JSON. There you can reserialize it to PHP and just keep this as a constant.

Answer (score 1):

If no framework is used, you can use an array of field => options.

```
$rules = [
            'user_name' => 'required',
            'user_email' => 'email required',
           // ...
         ];
```

And then feed them to some validator class, where rules are methods and they're being called inside validate method dynamically:

```
class Validator {

   public function __construct($data) { $this->data = $data; }
   private function required($field) {}
   private function email($email) {}
   // etc
   /** @method bool validate(array $rules) */
   public function validate($rules) {}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Never ever validate on client-side only. Always validate serverside.**

Usually you will have a base class for controller, and every other controller extends it.

Aa good approach is to have en every view controller (or the bootsrtap) a method check_params().
It should 1) get a copy or $_REQUEST, check every parameter needed, 2) delete $_REQUEST, 3) write back the checked and validated params.

```
abstract class controller_base {

    public function __construct() { ...; $this->check_param();...}

    protected final function check_param() {
        foreach ($this->param_list() AS $name => $type) {...}
    }

    abstract public function param_list();

}

class controller_login extends controller_base {

    public function param_list() {
        return array('name' => 'string', 'password' => 'string');
    }
}
```

The idea is that this way you

- only use params that has been sanitized
- you autmaticly delete every param not needed
- you have a list in every controller that states the used params.